# brick game bounce off the walls

Tags: python, pygame

I have a huge assignment due in class and Im lost like , asking god to spare me lost. Im making a brick game and the most basic function of getting the ball to bounce of the walls I cant figure out , my teacher is too busy and classmates are competitive , I dont want you to write the code for me, I just dont know how to code it. I keep getting errors and its just been hell the last couple of classes.

```
import math
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()                                   
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800,600])     
done = False                                    
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#DEFINE COLORS
WHITE = (255,255,255)                          
BLUE=(0,102,204)
LIGHT_BLUE=(0,0,204)
pink=(238,130,238)
#import images
#lives = pygame.image.load("heart.png")
# initialize font; must be called after 'pygame.init()' to avoid 'Font not Initialized' error
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
#var carying the space of the game
top = -100
left= -50
right= -750
bottom= -600
angle = math.radians(random.randint(-140,-30))

class game_screen():
    def draw_screen():
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,(50,100,700,600))
    def save_button():
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,pink,(500,20,50,30),0)
        save = "Save"
        label = myfont.render(save, 40, (0,0,0))
        screen.blit(label, (505, 20))
    def quit_button():
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,pink,(600,20,50,30),0)
        quit1 = "Quit"
        label = myfont.render(quit1, 40, (0,0,0))
        screen.blit(label, (605, 20))

        mX, mY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        mouseButtons = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if mouseButtons[0] == True:
            if (mX in range (600-20,600+20) and mY in range (20-20,20+20)):
                pygame.quit()
    #def display_lives():
        #lives_counter = screen.blit(lives,(50,30))

        #lives_counter2 = screen.blit(lives,(120,30))

        #lives_counter3 = screen.blit(lives,(190,30))

class PADDLE:
    def __init__(self,xpos,ypos):
        self.x = xpos
        self.y = ypos

    def draw(self): # draws paddle
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,pink,(self.x,self.y,70,20))


    def move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  #checking pressed keys
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            if self.x<=50:
                self.x=50
            else:
                self.x -= 10
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            if self.x >=680:
                self.x = 680
            else:
                self.x += 10

class BALL:
    def __init__(self,paddle1):
        self.x = (paddle1.x+35)
        self.y = (paddle1.y-5)
        self.speed = 0
        self.speedX = 0
        self.speedY = 0
        self.direction = 200

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,WHITE,(self.x,self.y),10)

    def bounce(self):
        self.direction = (180 - self.direction) % 360

    def move_ball(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  #checking pressed keys
        ball_on_paddle = True
        if ball_on_paddle == True :
            self.x = (paddle1.x+35)
            self.y = (paddle1.y-5)
            self.speed = 0

        if keys[pygame.K_UP] == True:
            ball_on_paddle = False
            print("a")
            self.speed = 10
            self.speedX += int(math.cos(angle)* self.speed)
            self.speedY += int(math.sin(angle)* self.speed)
            print(bottom)
            print(self.speedY)
            if self.y <= 0:
                self.bounce(0)
                self.y = 1

            if self.x <= 0:
                self.direction = (360 - self.direction) % 360
                self.x = 1

            if self.x > self.screenwidth - self.width:
                self.direction = (360 - self.direction) % 360
                self.x = self.screenwidth - self.width - 1


paddle1 = PADDLE(350,550)      
ball1 = BALL(paddle1)

# MAIN LOOP
while not done:
    screen.fill((LIGHT_BLUE))
    game_screen.draw_screen()
    game_screen.save_button()
    game_screen.quit_button()
    paddle1.draw()
    paddle1.move()
    ball1.draw()
    ball1.move_ball()
    ball1.bounce()




    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    pygame.display.flip()                      
    clock.tick(60)                              

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? What are you actually expecting it to do? Without any additional info, we can't really help you.

Comment: @radimpe its a brick breaker it should bounce off walls

Answer (score 1):

The collission between ball and wall can be detected by comparing the ball's coordinates with the coordinates of the walls. Reflecting the ball means a multiplication of either speedX or speedY - depending on the wall - with -1.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to make a function bounce(self) in your class BALL.

First, you decide which  **border**  you touch.

Then, you change the  **angle**  of the ball according to which border you bounce on. 
 If you work in a 360-degree system, the angle is mirrored:

- around a vertical axis when the ball bounces of the bottom and the top border. So  *angle = 180 - angle.*
- around a horizontal axis when the ball bounces of the side borders. So  *angle = - angle* .

And lastly, you have to  **move the ball back**  what it has travelled too much.[image: The ball moves in 1 iteration from C1 to C3']

Like you can see, the ball travels in 1 iteration from C1 to C3', while we want it to go to C3. We can achieve this by reflecting it around the axis BOUNDARY_X - ball_size. 
The new x-coordinate of the ball becomes then  *x = BOUNDARY_X - ball_size - (x - BOUNDARY_X + ball_size) = 2*(BOUNDARY_X - ball_size) - x* .

When we cast that into code, we get:
    class BALL:
        def bounce(self):
            if self.x < ball_size:
            self.angle = math.pi - self.angle
            self.x = 2*ball_size - self.x
        elif self.x > DISPLAY_WIDTH - ball_size:
            self.angle = math.pi - self.angle
            self.x = 2*(DISPLAY_WIDTH - ball_size) - self.x

```
    if self.y < ball_size:
        self.angle = - self.angle
        self.y = 2*ball_size - self.y
    elif self.y > DISPLAY_HEIGHT - ball_size:
        self.angle = - self.angle
        self.y = 2*(DISPLAY_HEIGHT - ball_size) - self.y
```